# Nodejs mysql .query() with Crypto.PBKDF2() difference?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, cryptojs

```
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, { hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000});
const sql = `
  SELECT
    p.PRIVILEGE_LEVEL_NAME, user.USER_ID, user.USER_NAME ,user.PERMITTED_FUNCTIONS
  FROM
    user_priviledge_table p
  INNER JOIN
    user_account_table user on user.PRIVILEGE_LEVEL = p.PRIVILEGE_LEVEL
  WHERE
    user.user_name='${req.body.user_name}' and user.password='${key}' LIMIT 1
`;

const [payload] = await db.query(sql);
```

It would equal to the same result as:

```
const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, { hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000});
const sql = `
  SELECT
    p.PRIVILEGE_LEVEL_NAME, user.USER_ID, user.USER_NAME ,user.PERMITTED_FUNCTIONS
  FROM
    user_priviledge_table p
  INNER JOIN
    user_account_table user on user.PRIVILEGE_LEVEL = p.PRIVILEGE_LEVEL
  WHERE
    user.user_name=? and user.password=? LIMIT 1
`;
const [payload] = await db.query(sql, [req.body.user_name, key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)]);
```

I want to know how `db.query(sql)` could hex the WordArray object to String and the exact difference between these two methods.

Which one would be better to use?

Answer (score 1):

`query()` method is structured by this way:

```
Connection.prototype.query = function query(sql, values, cb) {
  var query = Connection.createQuery(sql, values, cb);
  query._connection = this;

  if (!(typeof sql === 'object' && 'typeCast' in sql)) {
    query.typeCast = this.config.typeCast;
  }

  if (query.sql) {
    query.sql = this.format(query.sql, query.values);
  }

  if (query._callback) {
    query._callback = wrapCallbackInDomain(this, query._callback);
  }

  this._implyConnect();

  return this._protocol._enqueue(query);
};
```

`createQuery()`

```
Connection.createQuery = function createQuery(sql, values, callback) {
  if (sql instanceof Query) {
    return sql;
  }

  var cb      = callback;
  var options = {};

  if (typeof sql === 'function') {
    cb = sql;
  } else if (typeof sql === 'object') {
    options = Object.create(sql);

    if (typeof values === 'function') {
      cb = values;
    } else if (values !== undefined) {
      Object.defineProperty(options, 'values', { value: values });
    }
  } else {
    options.sql = sql;

    if (typeof values === 'function') {
      cb = values;
    } else if (values !== undefined) {
      options.values = values;
    }
  }

  if (cb !== undefined) {
    cb = wrapCallbackInDomain(null, cb);

    if (cb === undefined) {
      throw new TypeError('argument callback must be a function when provided');
    }
  }

  return new Query(options, cb);
};
```

check [files](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/3430c513d6b0ca279fb7c79b210c9301e9315658/lib/Connection.js#L180)

On the other hand I think that the two methods you describe are technically the same, the difference is the way the values are passed, also normally in the documentation we can find 3 ways to invoke `query()`.

The simplest form of .query() is `.query(sqlString, callback)`, where a **SQL** string is the first argument and the second is a callback:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = "David"', function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

The second form `.query(sqlString, values, callback)` comes when using placeholder values (see escaping query values):

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?', ['David'], function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

The third form `.query(options, callback)` comes when using various advanced options on the query, like escaping query values, joins with overlapping column names, timeouts, and type casting.

```
connection.query({
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?',
  timeout: 40000, // 40s
  values: ['David']
}, function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

Comment: thx for answer, so could u explain how db.query(sql) could hex the WordArray object to String? and which method suggest to use?

Comment: I don't think I can do it, but this could help you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex I also see that there are sections of code in the official repository that uses a similar method ```toString('hex')```